# How to create a pre-commit hook in SVNto limit file size?

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook, svn-hooks

I am new in creating pre-commit hooks on SVN. Is there anyone who knows how to limit file size that being committed to SVN? I am currently using TortoiseSVN.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? That the amount of committed changes are limited in size, that newly added files are limited in size, or that any file that exists in the repository is limited in size?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant how to create / write a pre-hook script to limit the file size when I click the button 'Commit'?

Answer (score 1):

- *Client-side* program used by you is irrelevant for *server-side* SVN hooks
- **Core** of your hook is two subcommands of `svnlook`

  1. With `svnlook changed` you'll get list of all files in transaction
  2. Using `svnlook filesize` for every file from the step 1 you'll get size of object in bytes, which you can compare with known limit and reject transaction, if needed
- **Technical details** of implementations heavily depends from server's OS and used shell